# Log printing increasing number of times with each method call

Tags: java, log4j

I have a spring method for logging method calls, and a JUnit test for the same, which has 6 tests. With each nth test, the log prints the relevant info n times. So, when the first test is run, its info is printed once (as should be), when the second is run, its info is printed twice and so on. Weirdly, this is happening only on the Eclipse console - the log file itself is perfectly OK.
What's going wrong?

Here's the code :
The spring aspect for logging.

```
public class LogAspect {

    /**
     * The LOG object to which all the details are sent.
     */
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(LogAspect.class);

    /**
     * Pointcut to identify methods annotated with @LogWithReturnValue.
     */
    @Pointcut("@annotation(com.skyfall.aspects.LogWithReturnValue)")
    public void logWithReturnValuePointcut() {
    }

    /**
     * Pointcut to identify methods annotated with @Log.
     */
    @Pointcut("@annotation(com.skyfall.aspects.Log)")
    public void logPointcut() {
    }

    /**
     * Pointcut to identify methods annotated with @LogWithArguments.
     */
    @Pointcut("@annotation(com.skyfall.aspects.LogWithArguments)")
    public void logWithArgumentsPointcut() {
    }

    /**
     * Pointcut to identify methods annotated with @LogWithArgumentsAndReturnValue.
     */
    @Pointcut("@annotation(com.skyfall.aspects.LogWithArgumentsAndReturnValue)")
    public void logWithArgumentsAndReturnValuePointcut() {
    }

    /**
     * Pointcut to identify methods annotated with @Metrics.
     * 
     * @param metrics
     *            Used to access the parameters of the annotation.
     */
    @Pointcut("@annotation(metrics)")
    public void metricsPointcut(com.skyfall.aspects.Metrics metrics) {
    }

    /**
     * Logs "Entering Method : className.methodName"
     * 
     * @param joinPoint
     */
    @Before("logPointcut()")
    public void logBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        LOG.info("Entering Method : ".concat(getClassAndName(joinPoint)));
    }

    /**
     * Logs "Entering Method : className.methodName". Also, the list of parameters as : param1 : value1, param2 :
     * value2, ...
     * 
     * @param joinPoint
     */
    @Before("logWithArgumentsPointcut()")
    public void logWithArgumentsBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        LOG.info("Entering Method : ".concat(getClassAndName(joinPoint)));
        LOG.info(getParams(joinPoint));
    }

    /**
     * Logs "Exiting Method : className.methodName"
     * 
     * @param joinPoint
     */
    @After(" logPointcut() || logWithArgumentsPointcut()")
    public void logAfter(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        LOG.info("Exiting Method : ".concat(getClassAndName(joinPoint)).concat("\n"));
    }

    /**
     * Logs calls to methods annotated with @LogWithReturnValue
     * 
     * @param joinPoint
     * @return Returns whatever object is returned by the annotated method.
     * @throws Throwable
     *             In case the method throws an exception.
     */
    @Around("logWithReturnValuePointcut()")
    public Object logWithReturnValue(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        LOG.info("Entering Method : ".concat(getClassAndName(joinPoint)));
        Object retVal = joinPoint.proceed();
        LOG.info("Method returned : ".concat(retVal.toString()));
        LOG.info("Exiting Method : ".concat(getClassAndName(joinPoint)).concat("\n"));
        return retVal;
    }

    /**
     * Logs calls to methods annotated with @LogWithArgumentsAndReturnValue
     * 
     * @param joinPoint
     * @return Returns whatever object is returned by the annotated method.
     * @throws Throwable
     *             In case the method throws an exception.
     */
    @Around("logWithArgumentsAndReturnValuePointcut()")
    public Object logWithArgumentsAndReturnValue(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        LOG.info("Entering Method : ".concat(getClassAndName(joinPoint)));
        LOG.info(getParams(joinPoint));
        Object retVal = joinPoint.proceed();
        LOG.info("Method returned : ".concat(retVal.toString()));
        LOG.info("Exiting Method : ".concat(getClassAndName(joinPoint)).concat("\n"));
        return retVal;
    }

    /**
     * Logs methods annotated with @Metrics, that exit successfully. Also calculates their running time, and creates a
     * UserEvent object to enter into the database. However, that part is not working for now.
     * 
     * @param joinPoint
     * @param metrics
     *            Contains the parameters, if any, passed to the annotation.
     * @return Returns whatever object is returned by the annotated method.
     * @throws Throwable
     *             In case the method throws an exception.
     */
    @Around("metricsPointcut(metrics)")
    public Object metricsTime(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, com.skyfall.aspects.Metrics metrics) throws Throwable {
        LOG.info("Entering Method : ".concat(getClassAndName(joinPoint)));
        LOG.info(("EventEnum : ").concat(metrics.eventEnum().toString()));
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Object retVal = joinPoint.proceed();
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long executionTime = endTime - startTime;
        StringBuffer logMessage = new StringBuffer();
        logMessage.append("Execution time : ");
        logMessage.append(executionTime);
        logMessage.append(" ms");
        LOG.info(logMessage.toString());
        LOG.info("Exiting Method : ".concat(getClassAndName(joinPoint)).concat("\n"));

        if (metrics.args() == 0) {
            UserEvent userEvent = userEventMaker(joinPoint.getClass().getSimpleName(), joinPoint.getSignature()
                    .getName(), metrics.eventEnum(), 0, null, executionTime, 1, retVal);
        } else {
            UserEvent userEvent = userEventMaker(joinPoint.getClass().getSimpleName(), joinPoint.getSignature()
                    .getName(), metrics.eventEnum(), 1, getParamsList(joinPoint), executionTime, 1, retVal);
        }

        return retVal;
    }

    /**
     * Logs a method annotated with @Metrics in case it throws an exception.
     * 
     * @param joinPoint
     * @param metrics
     *            Contains the parameters, if any, passed to the annotation.
     * @param ex
     *            The exception that was thrown by the method.
     */
    @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "metricsPointcut(metrics)", throwing = "ex")
    public void metricsExceptions(JoinPoint joinPoint, com.skyfall.aspects.Metrics metrics, Exception ex) {
        if (metrics.args() == 0) {
            UserEvent userEvent = userEventMaker(joinPoint.getClass().getSimpleName(), joinPoint.getSignature()
                    .getName(), metrics.eventEnum(), 0, null, 0, 0, null, ex.toString());
        } else {
            UserEvent userEvent = userEventMaker(joinPoint.getClass().getSimpleName(), joinPoint.getSignature()
                    .getName(), metrics.eventEnum(), 1, getParamsList(joinPoint), 0, 0, null, ex.toString());
        }
        LOG.info(getClassAndName(joinPoint).concat(" has thrown an exception: " + ex.toString()).concat("\n"));
    }
```

The JUnit test:

```
public class AspectTest extends BasePersistenceTest {

    @Before
    public void before() {

    }

    @Test
    public void testLog() {
        logAspectTester.logF(42);
    }

    @Test
    public void testLogWA() {
        logAspectTester.logWAF(42, 7, "string");
    }

    @Test
    public void testLogWRV() {
        logAspectTester.logWRVF(42);
    }

    @Test
    public void testLogWAARV() {
        logAspectTester.logWAARVF(42, 7, "string");
    }

    @Test
    public void testMetrics() {
        logAspectTester.metricsF(42);
    }

    @Test(expected = Exception.class)
    public void testMetricsE() {
        logAspectTester.metricsEF(42);
    }

}
```

And the log4j.properties file :

```
# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=logs/skyfall.log
log4j.appender.file.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n


# Root logger option
# Change log level to DEBUG instead of INFO if you want debug logs as well
# Append stdout in the end like (INFO, file, stdout) if you want to output logs message on the console as well (but don't commit)
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file

# Log everything. Good for troubleshooting
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=WARN
log4j.logger.org.apache.struts2 = WARN

# Log all JDBC parameters
#log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=ALL
```

Comment: What kind of console appender you are using? It sounds like the appender is configured per test (method).

Comment: are you able to attach the source code here, so we can take a look?

Comment: @heikkim I've added the log4j.properties file